# layout_alignParentBottom Not working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have one fragment layout xml with `RelativeLayout` containing `AdView` with attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` but it is not getting aligned at bottom.

I also have another layout xml where this code is working. Please see two files below.

fragment_info:(Here `AdView` not gets aligned to bottom)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/blogInfoWebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewBlogInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/blog_info_ad_unit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_search:(Here `AdView` get aligned to bottom)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Some code -->

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/fragment_post_list_web_view" />

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adViewSearchList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/search_list_ad_unit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: give the webview with the full height properties:  `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Check this Out with Linear Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refreshIndicator"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/blogInfoWebView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adViewBlogInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/blog_info_ad_unit" />

    </LinearLayout>
```